# PowerBI servers list

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, firewall

I have a fact table in Postgresql database and I what to build a PowerBI analysis with PowerBI professional.
If I let Postgresql accept connections from all internet IP addresses, it works but it is not safe. I'd like to limit the access only to Power BI servers.
How can I identify PowerBI incoming traffic? Is there a best practice to set up the firewall?

Comment: You'll need to add the Azure DC IP's to your white list https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I prefered to update once in a while my pg_hba.conf with the white list from the official Microsoft list. The production file is overwrittern with a new file. The script replaces a comment line

```
#PowerBI
```

in a template pg_hba.conf file with the new list

With the new list

```
import requests

whiteListUrl = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20210524.json"
modelFile = "/path/to/template/pg_hba.conf"
outputFileName = "/path/to/production/pg_hba.conf"
userName = "power_bi"

response = requests.get(whiteListUrl)
whiteLists = response.json()

for group in whiteLists["values"]:
    if group["name"]!='PowerBI':
        continue
    text_file = open(modelFile, "r").read()
    whiteList = ""
    for address in group["properties"]["addressPrefixes"]:
        whiteList += "host    all     {}             {}            md5\n".format(userName, address)
    text_file = text_file.replace("#PowerBI", whiteList)

    textfile = open(outputFileName, "w")
    a = textfile.write(text_file)
    textfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not open any connections from Internet. Yes, you can get a list of all Azure IP addresses, but this does not limit them to Power BI only, plus it is a manual process to update the list few times a year. A lot better solution is to install [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) in your network, which will allow [connecting from Power BI Service to your server on-premise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/postgresql#connect-to-a-postgresql-database-from-power-query-online).

Comment: My server is a Linux Ubuntu macchine. I read that a native linux implementation is not yet avaliable.

Comment: You can install it on any Windows machine in your network, which can access the Postgresql server. It doesn't need to be on the *same* server.